# An Application of Montel's Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is an exercise is T.Gamelin's book "Complex Analysis".

> Let $f(z)$ be a bounded holomorphic function on the strip $\{ -1 < Im (z) < 1\}$, such that $f(x)$ tends to 0 as $x$ goes to +$\infty$ along the real axis. Show that for any $\epsilon$, $f(x+iy)$ tends to 0 as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, uniformly for $-1+\epsilon < y < 1-\epsilon$

My approach was to introduce the sequence of functions $f_n(z) = f(z+n)$ to sort of "push" the arguments towards +$\infty$ and apply Montel to get that a subseq. $f_{n_k}$ converges normally to  $g$ and $g(0)$ is 0. How should I proceed from here? I can see that $g$ should be the constant function but I can't see how to prove that. Any help?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I've noticed that too, but I'm stuck at proving that the limit is 0 for all y.

Comment: @user1952009 Extremely sorry, f is bounded.

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure how I can proceed this way,can you please elaborate?

Comment: Apply Montel's theorem to $f_n$ to obtain a locally uniformly convergent subsequence $f_{n_k}$ whose holomorphic limit is $g$. Use $f(x) \to 0$ so say $g = 0$ identically, and use the local uniform convergence to say $f(x+iy) \to 0$ uniformly on $|y| \le 1 - \epsilon$

Comment: @user1952009 how does $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ say g is identically 0 ?

Comment: $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(z+n_k) = g(z)$ means $g(x) = f(x+\infty) = 0$, and by the identity theorem $g$ must vanish identically

Comment: @user1952009 oh, damn!  I kept on trying to prove g(iy) = 0, thanks!